# Is there a way to check access to frame?

Tags: javascript, iframe, frame

I want to bind an event to some frames from a parent window. But if a frame has different url I haven't access to it. Is there way to get url of child frame or to check access to them. I use such method:

```
for (var i = 0; i<window.frames.length; i++)
{
    try 
    {
        if (window.frames[i].document);
        ...
    } 
    catch (err) 
    {
    }
}
```

P.S. I also want to know is there a way to distinguish frames and iframes in the window.frames elements?